# ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.1, chirp

I am using Chirp SDK for ultrasonic in xcode10.1. I am getting this warning message in log multiple times :

> [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown
>   selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)

I tried the below one

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()  

    do {  
      try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, options: .defaultToSpeaker)  
      try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)  
    } catch {  
      print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")  
    }
```

But still shows warning for me. How to fix this warning.Thanks in advance

Comment: You can read some information [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108785)

Comment: @Kamran: check my edited code.tried still shows warning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dan from Chirp here. Unfortunately, this warning is a known issue in the current Chirp iOS SDK (3.4.3) on certain devices and it can't be remedied by code on the user side. It's scheduled to be fixed in the next release, due out in the next few weeks. It is benign, however, and won't affect functionality.

Comment: If I submit the app with this warning will it approve in appstore.

Comment: Now i am sending data over ultrasonic but it sends upto 8 bytes.is there any possibility to send more data. Now i am using free account, in this account has some limitations.